# How episerver CMS stores local datetime values to UTC

Tags: episerver

When we publish page in episerver (version 11) in CMS edit mode, page's  "Published date time value" shows (in CMS edit mode) in user's local timezone ( i.e. specific to user's browser culture)

But I'm aware EPiServer stores datetime values in UTC format in database.

Can you please advise how it is converted to UTC from local time value while saving in database ? Please suggest how can i explore it ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have access to the source code but would say that most likely they use [DateTime.ToUniversalTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?view=net-5.0) Why do you need to know? What is the issue that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have to do reverse... I have some datetime value (received from service) in UTC. Now I have to show in view in local culture based on user's timezones ?

Answer (score 1):

Tried the [DateTime.ToLocalTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=net-5.0)? Should give you what you want.

```
univDateTime = DateTime.Parse(strDateTime); 
localDateTime = univDateTime.ToLocalTime();
```